# SQLite extensions error, c to dll compiling

Tags: database, sqlite, ubuntu

**What is needed:**

Compile the json1 extension for SQLite

**What I did:**

Reaserched the official extension page: *https://sqlite.org/loadext.html*

Downloaded the SQLite source code: *https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/trunk/README.md*

Found 2 ways to compile a dll:

1. `cl windows command`
2. `gcc linux command`

For the `cl` command I installed Visual Studio and launched the vcvars32.bat file for the enviroment launch, then tried this command: `cl ext/misc/json1.c sqlite3ext.h /link /dll`.
Docs: *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-command-line-syntax?view=vs-2019*

However it didnt work and I got an error: `fatal error C1083: sqlite3ext.h: No such file or directory`.
I have the `sqlite3ext.h` file and tried moving it arround but nothing worked.

Then I moved to the `gcc` command:

1. I used the `Ubuntu wsl`
2. Upadated Ubuntu
3. Downloaded the source code (mensioned above)
4. Installed the SQLite developer package (can't find it)
5. Used this command: `gcc -g -shared sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c -o json1.dll`

*Found the command on the SQLite extension page mensioned above*

`It didn't work and I got this long error message:`

```
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c: In function ‘jsonEachConnect’:
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2099:29: error: ‘SQLITE_VTAB_INNOCUOUS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SQLITE_STATIC’?
     sqlite3_vtab_config(db, SQLITE_VTAB_INNOCUOUS);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                             SQLITE_STATIC
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2099:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c: At top level:
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2501:3: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
   0                          /* xShadowName */
   ^
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2501:3: note: (near initialization for ‘jsonEachModule’)
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2529:3: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
   0                          /* xShadowName */
   ^
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2529:3: note: (near initialization for ‘jsonTreeModule’)
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c: In function ‘sqlite3Json1Init’:
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2594:8: error: ‘SQLITE_INNOCUOUS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SQLITE_IGNORE’?
        SQLITE_INNOCUOUS;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        SQLITE_IGNORE
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2602:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_create_window_function’; did you mean ‘sqlite3_create_function’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     rc = sqlite3_create_window_function(db, aAgg[i].zName, aAgg[i].nArg,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          sqlite3_create_function
sqlite/ext/misc/json1.c:2603:34: error: ‘SQLITE_SUBTYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SQLITE_CANTOPEN’?
                                  SQLITE_SUBTYPE | enc, 0,
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!**

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with the SQLite UUID extension using "better-sqlite", but that's something else. What I did was replace everything that said `SQLITE_INNOCUOUS` and `SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC` with `SQLITE_IGNORE`. And it worked, at least for this extension. Something like the following:

***Before:***

```
{
  int rc = SQLITE_OK;
  SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi);
  (void)pzErrMsg;  /* Unused parameter */
  rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "uuid", 0, SQLITE_UTF8|SQLITE_INNOCUOUS, 0,
                               sqlite3UuidFunc, 0, 0);
  if( rc==SQLITE_OK ){
    rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "uuid_str", 1, 
                       SQLITE_UTF8|SQLITE_INNOCUOUS|SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC,
                       0, sqlite3UuidStrFunc, 0, 0);
  }
  if( rc==SQLITE_OK ){
    rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "uuid_blob", 1,
                       SQLITE_UTF8|SQLITE_INNOCUOUS|SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC,
                       0, sqlite3UuidBlobFunc, 0, 0);
  }
  return rc;
}
```

***After:***

```
{
  int rc = SQLITE_OK;
  SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2(pApi);
  (void)pzErrMsg; /* Unused parameter */
  rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "uuid", 0, SQLITE_UTF8 | SQLITE_IGNORE, 0,
                               sqlite3UuidFunc, 0, 0);
  if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "uuid_str", 1,
                                 SQLITE_UTF8 | SQLITE_IGNORE | SQLITE_IGNORE,
                                 0, sqlite3UuidStrFunc, 0, 0);
  }
  if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "uuid_blob", 1,
                                 SQLITE_UTF8 | SQLITE_IGNORE | SQLITE_IGNORE,
                                 0, sqlite3UuidBlobFunc, 0, 0);
  }
  return rc;
}
```

***Edit***

---

I just had to declare this at the beginning of the code.

```
#define SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC    0x000000800
#define SQLITE_DIRECTONLY       0x000080000
#define SQLITE_SUBTYPE          0x000100000
#define SQLITE_INNOCUOUS        0x000200000
```